# How to set usb Drive with executable permission

Tags: usb, steam, chromebook

I have Steam on my Chromebook (Acer c710) With Saucy, Unity.
I was just about to download Dota 2 when I didn't have enough space on my device, so I had a spare usb Flash Drive(Sandisk Cruzer Faucet) and I tried to download it directly to there.
Everything would have went fine, except I ran into an error:"Your file system must have executable permission".

I want to know how I could mount my USB Drive with executable permission.

Thank you.

Comment: What filesystem is your USB drive using? NTFS?

Comment: No, I am pretty sure it is FAT.

Answer (score 2):

If the partition is NTFS or FAT, you'll have to mount it with the correct permissions for files to be executable.

Use the `lsblk` command to identify your USB drive (let's call it `/dev/sdb1`). You can either mount it manually (I picked a folder called `usbdrive`, pick what you want):

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
mkdir ~/usbdrive
sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 /dev/sdb1 usbdrive
```

Or add an entry to `fstab`:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
mkdir -p ~/usbdrive
echo '/dev/sdb1 /home/user/usbdrive vfat rw,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Replace `sdb1` with the identifier of your USB drive, and the paths to `usbdrive` to wherever you want your drive to be mounted.

Comment: Ok, I have 2 questions, Do I do this in linux terminal(xterm) or the one in chrome(ctrl+alt+t) and what does identifier mean? Is it like the model(Cruzer faucet) or something else?

Comment: @user306664 I think you can use either terminal, as long as you can access `/etc/fstab`. By identifier, I mean something like `sda1`, `hdb1`, etc - these are used to identify partitions. The `lsblk` command will show partitions in a tree form, with the identifier.

Comment: Ok, Steam now sees it as Executable, although I can't clear the space on it, I can't format it, how Would I do that, and thank you for taking this question in consideration

Comment: @user306664 maybe your `uid` and `gid` values are different. What's the output of `id`?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo fdisk -l`
`sudo umount /dev/sdb1`
`sudo mount -o rw,exec /dev/sdb1 /mnt`
1st command will help you in identifying Device name
2nd will unmount your usb(suppose Device name is /dev/sdb1)
3rd will mount it with permissions of Read,write & Execution.

Comment: ok, now my usb drive has execute but not write permissions